# Keystone crashes inside Turborepo

Tags: next.js, monorepo, keystonejs, turborepo

[Keystone](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone) fails to find dependencies while running `yarn build` inside a new [Turborepo](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo) project.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Install Turborepo in a new project `npx create-turbo@latest`
2. navigate to the apps folder or wherever you plan to install Keystone cd apps/
3. install keystone `yarn create keystone-app`
4. navigate back to the root directory `cd ../`
5. add `.keystone/** to turbo.json` Pipeline:

```
"build": {"dependsOn": [ "^build" ], "outputs": [ ".next/**", ".keystone/admin/.next/**" ]}}
```

6. build project from root directory `cd ../ && yarn build`

Observe error message from inside `./keystone`

[image]

### turbo.json

```
{
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "^build"
      ],
      "outputs": [
        ".next/**",
        ".keystone/admin/.next/**"
      ]
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    },
    "clean": {
      "cache": false
    }
  },
  "globalDependencies": [
    "tsconfig.json",
    ".prettierrc.json",
    ".eslintrc.json",
    "Procfile"
  ]
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*",
    "apps/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "dev": "turbo run dev --no-cache --parallel --continue",
    "lint": "turbo run lint",
    "test": "turbo run test",
    "clean": "turbo run clean && rm -rf node_modules",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,js,md}\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "turbo": "latest"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.18"
}
```

### apps/keystoneCMS/package.json

```
{
  "name": "logly-admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "keystone.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "keystone dev",
    "start": "keystone start",
    "build": "keystone build && keystone prisma migrate deploy",
    "postinstall": "keystone postinstall"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/css": "^11.7.1",
    "@keystone-6/auth": "^1.0.1",
    "@keystone-6/cloudinary": "^1.0.0",
    "@keystone-6/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@keystone-6/fields-document": "^1.0.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.8.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "postcss": "^8.4.7",
    "tailwind": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^14.15 || ^16.13"
  }
}
```

Github issue for more context: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/7518

Versions
Node: v16.13.1 (latest)
Keystone: v6 (latest)
Turborepo: 1.2.8 (latest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to replicate this, and it looks to be an issue with the `next` version that `npx create-turbo@latest` installs and is pinned to. Running `create-turbo` installs `next` `12.0.8` and is pinned to that version. Keystone requires at least version `12.1.0`.

When I changed my `./apps/web/package.json` to:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "ui": "*"
  },
```

The error no longer occurred.